# I m getting an error while installing MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I m getting an error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )" while installing MySQLdb for my project i hv tried for python 2.7 & 3.6

Comment: maybe it has different name - like `mysqldb` ? or maybe it doesn't exist any more? There are other modules. I prefer [mysql-connector](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) because it is created by authors of database MySQL.

Comment: yup using mysql-connector I was able to connect with server.

Comment: when i install mysql client then this module  worked for me ...able to import it